# Отлов окна и програмное нажатие на кнопку

Tags: delphi

Можно ли отловить как-то окно (при открытии), что бы на нем сразу программно нажать на кнопку?

Answer (score 2):

Если кнопка одна , то ловишь окно и отправляй сообщение, если кнопок несколько то ловишь окно перебираешь кнопки и при нахождении нужной отправляешь сообщение.
Примеров в гугле много.

[Вот один из примеров](http://www.delphibeginer.zbord.ru/viewtopic.php?t=77).

**ДОБАВЛЕНО**

```
h1 := FindWindow (nil, 'Загрузка файла');  
if  h1<> 0  then
  begin
  h2 := FindWindowEx(h1, 0,'Button', '&Сохранить');
  SendMessage(h2,BM_CLICK,0,0)
  end;
```

Этот код ищет окно с название **Загрузка файла** и нажимает на кнопку **Сохранить**

Comment: Я понялчто это называется так: надо найти handle окна и по нему можно нажать кнопку. Но немогу выстроить всю цепочку, помогите еще немного. как же это делается ?

Comment: @oldzas...

     Я понял, что это называется так: надо найти handle окна и по нему можно нажать кнопку. Но не могу выстроить всю цепочку, помогите еще немного. как же это делается?

...рано вы полезли в эту область...вам бы на бейсике побыдлокодить всякие там калькуляторы...но не это. Иначе пользователи ваших "программ" будут страдать и проклинать вас =)